# Setting default value when linking back to previously visited page?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, session

In my current MVC project, I need to be able to set the default value of a `<input type="range"... />` to the value that it already has been assigned as, using a `Session` variable.

```
<input name="answer" type="range" id="slider" defaultValue="@Session["Question5Answer"]" min="10" max="200" />
```

This works if I click the back button in the browser, but not if I click a different button on another page that links back to this page.

I know that the session variable is saved, because there is a submit button on the same page as this `<input type="range"... />` which links to another page, which does display the `Session` variable's value. And yet whenever I click a link on *that* page which sends be straight back to the page with the `<input type="range"... />` on it, the `defaultValue` is not set to the value of the `Session` variable, and yet when I use the browser's back button, it does save and the `defaultValue` is set to the value of the `Session` vairable.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? If there is any more snippets of code that would be required for answering this question, just let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it should be value instead of defaultValue , defaultValue is a DOM property , also check in what html gets generated

Comment: @vishalsharma that fixed things, thanks!

Comment: I am adding this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

`defaultValue` is a DOM Property , html markup equivalent for defaultValue is `value` property.

see here :

`value` : https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/text

`defaultValue` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Hope that helps..